# Existing auxillary hard drives slow to load on windows 7 reinstall

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Every time I have reinstalled windows 7 my aux HDDs always take time to load up when browsing files on them. Once they are loaded they seem to be fine for awhile. After awhile they seem to have the same issue. I never had this problem when the drive was originally installed with the previous windows 7 install. It's as if it sees it as a foreign drive and not one natively configured for my computer. I don't seem to have this problem for my SSDs.

Sorry if this seems trivial or a simple google search, but I had no luck finding an answer. It just seems like my scenario is very specific and hard to keyword properly on google.

Comment: They probably spin down because they haven't been in use for X amount of time. I think it's somewhere in the power options if you want to change that behavior.

Comment: Yeah but it seems weird that it's exclusive to foreign drives and not fresh ones formatted for the current OS install. I'll look into it though.

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model of your computer? What drives (manufacturer & model) have you tried inserting?

Comment: There usually is "always" something happening on your system drive so it's not spinning down. Other drives can be spun down if there is no activity.